# Два обстоятельства одного вида, находящиеся рядом

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, уточнения, обстоятельство

**У них в Instagram, в комментариях постоянно сидят боты.** (Однородные обстоятельства места: у них и в Instagram, и в комментариях сидят боты. Неверно.)

**У них в Instagram, в комментариях, постоянно сидят боты.** (Второе обстоятельство уточняет первое: у них в Instagram, а именно в комментариях, сидят боты.)

А если написать так:

**У них в Instagram в комментариях постоянно сидят боты.**

Получается, что Instagram находится в комментариях, а это неверно. Или можно считать два обстоятельства места независимыми, полагать, что они характеризуют место с разных сторон, не образуя пару уточняемое-уточняющее и не являясь однородными?

> Иногда ряды обстоятельств могут быть лишены уточняющего оттенка значения и восприниматься (в данном контексте!) как разные стороны одного явления, без смысловой подчинённости.
>   *Несколько человек идут **по снегу через улицу в хату*** (Быков). (https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html)

Тот же вопрос с другим примером:

**Пройдите стажировку ещё во время учёбы — тогда к окончанию вуза вы будете иметь красивую строчку в резюме в разделе «Опыт работы».**

Очевидно, что резюме не находится в разделе "Опыт работы", — как раз наоборот. Но если не задумывается уточнение, то допустимо ли не ставить запятую?

Comment: Что значит "в комментариях сидят боты"? Боты пишут комментарии? Тогда я бы написал  "на комментариях сидят боты".

Comment: Я понимаю, что можно  "сидеть в чате", но сидеть "в комментариях"? А "сидеть на" означает заниматься определенным видом деятельности (сидеть на кассе, на выдаче товаров).

Comment: Просто разговорный вариант: "в комментариях", то есть "в разделе с комментариями от подписчиков". Думаю, здесь не нужно сильно придираться. Ну и кстати, вариант "сидеть на комментариях" точно неуместен.

Comment: Если есть такой раздел "Комментарии", то согласен, я Instagram не пользуюсь, думал комментарии дают к каждому сообщению отдельно.

Comment: @М_Г Под каждой фотографией, которую пользователь выкладывает в Instagram, подписчики могут оставлять комментарии. В моём предложении   фрагмент "в Instagram в комментариях" можно развернуть до "в аккаунте пользователя в Instagram в разделе с комментариями под опубликованными им фотографиями".

Comment: Так я был прав, нет такого единого раздела, под каждой фотографией свой "раздел".  Нет такого общего раздела "комментарии",  в котором сидят боты. И боты не сидят под каждой фотографией. Поэтомы я и восстал против "в комментариях".

Comment: @М_Г Хорошо: "в комментариях" = "в разделе с комментариями под некоторыми фотографиями (возможно, всеми)". Специалистам по маркетингу в социальных сетях это разговорное выражение будет вполне понятно.

Comment: Раз нет единого пространства под названием "комментарии", то слово постоянно ( "постоянно сидят в комментариях"), на мой взглад, относится к каждому разделу комментариев в отдельности (постоянно сидят в этом  постоянно сидят в том). А не проще ли сказать "постоянно пишут комментарии" — и никаких вопросов!

Comment: @М_Г Давайте так: слово "комментарии" обозначает разделы комментариев под всеми фотографиями как единое условное пространство. "В комментариях" указывает на нахождение в этом пространстве, не вдаваясь в подробности, в разделах с комментариями под какими именно фотографиями сидят боты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> У них в Instagram в комментариях постоянно сидят боты. Получается, что Instagram находится в комментариях, а это неверно.

Такой формальный подход неверен. "Кто в ком сидит" определается по смыслу, а порядок может быть как от общего к частному, так и от частного к общему.

Возьмем город, улицу, особняк. Оба вариана (как от общего к частному, так и от частного к общему) можно найти в Нацкорпусе:

> Ведь надо было попытаться сплотить под одним стягом таких разных людей, как миллионер Гинзбург, живущий **в Санкт-Петербурге в роскошном особняке**, и бедняка Кацмана, ютящегося в полутемном подвале **на Сумской улице в городе Харькове**. [Е. А. Кацман. Молчать нельзя! // «Огонек». № 12, 1970]
>
> **В нашем городе на улице Первомайской** открывается родильный дом, построенный на средства от коммунистического субботника. [Я этой силы частица… // «Работница», 1980]

Comment: Получается, выражение «на поляне между кустами» может быть воспринято двояко?

Comment: Формально говоря, получается двояко: то ли кусты стоят на поляне, то ли поляна расположена между кустами, но, по-моему, на поляне только трава растет, поэтому я  понимаю, что поляна расположена между кустами.

Comment: На «Лицее» сказано, что уточнение как раз вносит ясность: «2) В зависимости от смысла одни и те же слова могут рассматриваться как уточняющие или не как уточняющие обстоятельства. Сравните приводимые попарно предложения:
Далеко в лесу раздавались удары топора (слушатель тоже находится в лесу). – Далеко, в лесу, раздавались удары топора (слушатель находится вне леса).
Дети расположились на поляне между кустами (поляна окружена кустами, а на самой поляне их нет). – Дети расположились на поляне, между кустами (кусты находятся на самой поляне)».

Comment: https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html)

Comment: И до прочтения вашего ответа я думал, что уточнение обязательно, когда два обстоятельства располагаются в порядке от общего к частному, иначе получится наоборот. Оказалось, всё определяется по смыслу и уточнения может не быть.

Answer (score 3):

Про Instagram: верны Ваши варианты 2 и 3, недопустим 1.

То есть **2)** "второе обстоятельство уточняет первое" и **3)** "можно считать два обстоятельства места независимыми, полагать, что они характеризуют место с разных сторон, не образуя пару уточняемое-уточняющее и не являясь однородными", - зависит от акцентировки пишущего.

То же и с другим примером: если задумывается уточнение, то 
запятая ставится по определению, и, если не задумывается уточнение, нечего ей там делать.

Comment: То есть не идёт значение по умолчанию, что первое место находится во втором?

Comment: Вася, ну не поняла я вопроса коммента; исчо разок спросите, плиз...

Comment: Когда мы говорим "на поляне между кустами", это понимается так, что поляна окружена кустами, а не кусты находятся на поляне, т. е. место, обозначенное первым обстоятельством, находится внутри места, обозначенного вторым обстоятельством. Когда мы говорим "в Instagram в комментариях", стандартно это воспринимается так, что Instagram находится в комментариях. Но здесь, понимая ситуацию, мы воспринимаем смысл комбинации этих обстоятельств по-другому. Верно?

Comment: А впрочем пользователь М_Г в своём ответе уже прояснил этот момент.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант: *У них в Instagram на комментариях постоянно сидят боты.*

Здесь **неоднородные** отношения между обстоятельствами: где и на какой функции.

Так текст более понятен.

Comment: "В комментариях" = "в разделе с комментариями под некоторыми фотографиями пользователя (возможно, всеми)". Разговорный вариант между специалистами по маркетингу в социальных сетях. Вариант "на комментариях" неуместен по семантике. Аналогия с выражениями "сидеть на кассе", "сидеть на выдаче товаров" здесь невозможна.

Comment: 1) Наверное, Вам виднее, но разговорный вариант "сидеть на комментариях" в обще случае используется, например: Как заработать сидя дома на комментариях новичку?http://sid9doma.ru/zarabotok-na-kommentariyah/kak-zarabotat-na-kommentariyah-novichku.html  2) Даже с предлогом В эти обстоятельства желательно считать неоднородными, так как это не уточнение, а основная мысль сообщения: сидят именно в комментариях, а не где-нибудь еще.